# how to close a tab in opera based on its url

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I want to stop websites displaying ads, so I am looking for a way to create a script (opera extension) that can read the url info of any new created tap and close it automatically if contains a certain domain

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read into this documentation on [how to handle tabs in Opera addons](https://dev.opera.com/extensions/tab-window/). It answers all your questions.

Basically you can modify this example code (that I have taken from the linked docs and modified slightly) and modify it to your needs:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        'currentWindow': true,
        'url': pattern //<-- Your URL pattern
    // This will match all tabs to the pattern we specified
    }, function(tab) {
        // Remove all tabs that match the URL pattern
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.map(t => t.id))
    });
});
```